# Add to insert table+row in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Description

I have a table within a table. Consider the scenario that `class="maintable"` has three rows. The sub table is showing add and delete buttons in a row so we can add and delete rows from the sub table.

But the problem occurs when `class="maintable"` has one row with a sub table which is empty. I want to add values into the sub table by add button.

### Error

We shouldn't see the sub table when it is empty. Instead we need to insert the rows when it is empty by clicking add button.

I need the add button at main table level if sub table values are the for a row, then click on the add button to add "row".
If sub table values are empty for a row then click on add to insert" same sub table + row.

Please let me know if you have any doubts.

Here is the markup and JS.

### HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="maintable">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Pos</b></td>
        <td><b>NICOMATIC P/N</b></td>
        <td><b>Client P/N</b></td>
        <td><b>Quantity Ordered</b></td>
        <td><b>Requested Date &nbsp;</b></td>
        <td><b>Discount</b></td>
        <td><b>Unit Price &nbsp;</b></td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>
        <apex:repeat value="{!q1}" var="i">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="90%" >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(rowNum)}" style="align:center;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdCustom">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!i.name}" /><apex:inputtext />
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdCustom">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!i.Client_P_N__c}" /><apex:inputtext />
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdCustom" style="width:100px;">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!i.order_batch__r}" var="obr">
                            <table id="table-data" border="1">
                                <tr class="tr_clone">
                                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!obr.Quantity_Ordered__c}" /></td>
                                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!obr.Requested_Date__c}" /></td>
                                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!obr.Discount__c}" /></td>
                                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!obr.Unit_price__c}" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" class="tr_clone_delete"/></td>
                                    <td class="tdCustom"><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script>
    $("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
        var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
        $tr.after($clone);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".tr_clone_delete").live('click', function() {
          var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          $tr.remove();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4L89kt9v/

Comment: short question = more answers , i didn't got the idea or the problem please provide a demo of your code here http://jsfiddle.net , and explain ur problem with few lines and ill help

Comment: Your chances of getting an answer will be way more If you provide a demo and explain what you want to do in i in one or two sentence. From this, i have no clue about what you're trying to explain or trying to do...